# Map not returning anything

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
def upload_to_s3(filepath, unique_id):
    # do something
    print s3_url # <-- Confirming that this `s3_url` variable is not None
    return s3_url


threads = []
for num, list_of_paths in enumerate(chunked_paths_as_list):
    for filepath in list_of_paths:
        t = threading.Thread(target=upload_to_s3, args=(filepath, self.unique_id))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
results = map(lambda t: t.join(), threads)
print results
```

Unfortunately, this is returning `None` for every item:

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>>>> TIME: 13.9884989262
```

What do I need to do to get the `return` statement in the above `map` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`t.join()` *always* returns `None`. That's because the return value of a thread target is ignored.

You'll have to collect your results by some other means, like a [`Queue` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue):

```
from Queue import Queue

results = Queue()

def upload_to_s3(filepath, unique_id):
    # do something
    print s3_url # <-- Confirming that this `s3_url` variable is not None
    results.put(s3_url)


threads = []
for num, list_of_paths in enumerate(chunked_paths_as_list):
    for filepath in list_of_paths:
        t = threading.Thread(target=upload_to_s3, args=(filepath, self.unique_id))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
for t in threads:
    t.join()

while not results.empty():
    print results.get()
```

Alternatively, use [`multiprocessing.dummy` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) to get the `multiprocessing.Pool` behaviour but with threads, which can do what you want; collect return values from the async function calls.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Could you please show me how I would use the `Queue` object in the above example?